# move panels that are created programmatically visual studio VB

Tags: vb.net

My first post... here it goes:
Using Visual Studio 2012 in VB
I'm generating a panel, adding 6 labels to it, then I want to move that panel across the screen based on a timer event.  I then want to generate another panel right behind the first and it do the same....add labels and move it across the screen with timers.

So I have it generating the panel and labels, but I don't know how to access the newly created panels to move them?  Since the panel isn't on the form to begin with my code won't let me access it.  Once they move completely across the screen I want to delete them.  This will basically go on forever.
    Dim count1 As Integer = 1

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    count1 = count1 + 1

    Dim Pan As Panel
    Dim Labelx As Label
    For x As Integer = 1 To 10 Step 1
        Pan = New Panel
        Pan.Name = "Panel" & Convert.ToString(x)
        Pan.Left = 300
        Pan.Top = 100 + 160 * (x - 1)
        Pan.Height = 150
        Pan.Width = 96
        Pan.BackColor = Color.Coral
        Controls.Add(Pan)

        For y As Integer = 1 To 6 Step 1
            Labelx = New Label
            Labelx.Name = "Labelx" & Convert.ToString(x)
            Labelx.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(5, 10)
            Labelx.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, y * 15) 'set your location
            Labelx.Text = "NEW" + Convert.ToString(y)
            Labelx.AutoSize = True
            Pan.Controls.Add(Labelx)
        Next
    Next
End Sub


'Here is an example of how I would normally move a panel, but since Panel1 doesn't exist, this code fails.

inc1 = Panel1.Location.X - convIncDiff
If inc1 > -90 Then Panel1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(inc1, Panel1.Location.Y)
```

Comment: You are making new panels and labels on every tick.  Don't do that.  Make the controls you want before the timer runs and then reference the controls through the parents control collection: Me.Controls("Panel1"), etc.  Use the Controls.ContainsKey function to test if the control name exists.

Comment: `Step 1` is the default, no need to type it.

Comment: Do the labels need to move independently inside the panel or is moving the panels what you need?

Comment: I'm just trying to move the panel so that the labels move with it.  I think LarsTech has got me on a good path by using Me.Controls("Panel1").  I just want to dynamically move each panel after it has been generated.

Comment: You need to save you panels into a private variable (form level) so you can access then in various methods. If you have them declared in the sub than you need to look at the forms `controls` array to find the panels.

Comment: What if I wanted to access (change the size of) the labels on the dynamically created panel?  In other words I want to access 'Me.Panel1.Controls("Label" & lblInc).Size= New System.Drawing.Point(0, 0)'  I want to make the 'Panel1' dynamic so I don't have to repeat it several times.